# A time limit for pull requests to be approved or interacted with

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

In our work repository, we have a few colleagues who are the "board members". These colleagues are the only ones who can approve a PR to be merged. If other colleagues reviewed and approved your PR, you still can not merge it.

Some times, a PR stays for weeks and weeks without getting an "admin" approval to be finally merged or even without any comments at all. This could be irritating as you have to constantly contact one of the admins and practically run after them asking for a few mins of his/her valuable time to just be kind enough to have a look on the code.

I'm wondering if there's some kind of a recommended ***standard approach*** for work environments with a time limit, that says for example: if after two weeks of no interaction from the "board members", the PR is automatically approved. I mean ***just as a way to put a little bit of pressure on the "board members"*** to have a look on the code.

Note: This question is related to work environments, not to open source projects of course.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it the answer is very dependent on your team an the board members.
Did you try to talk to your manager about the situation?
maybe you need more board members.

Also, maybe if you can started working in agile with sprints of 2 weeks.
then there will be time limit by the sprint borders end for every issue.

In my team each member can approve the issue of fellow members and it works well for as, you can see what others are doing and you have incentive to approve the issue in time, because the next time it will be your issue.

For more info on scrum, agile and sprints.
https://www.atlassian.com/agile/scrum/sprints

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The team members are around 55 with around 8 of them are board members. And as stated in the question, an approval of a non-board member doesn't qualify the PR to be merged. Regarding agile, yes we are working with agile sprints, but the two-week sprint limit, doesn't limit the PR time.

Comment: well maybe you should "end" issue when its after the PR, that sound like the right thing to me.